# Saving comma separated values in a file with Canopy Express (win 10)

Tags: python, csv, canopy

I am a Canopy Express user looking for a way to write to/read from csv files. The default installation of Canopy (on Win 10) does not seem to include the csv module. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the Python standard library, not an add-on package.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Did you try `import csv`?

Comment: I thought I had tried that. But now I am beginning to think that I might have wrongly typed "import cvs" which obviously caused a syntax error. It's  working now. Apologies for the silly post but your answer helped me see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If something I try doesn't "work right", I first look for typos. Then for mis-read instructions.  Then for poor assumptions... Etc.